# How to get mismatch records of two tables from same database in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Eg:

```
select username, country from table1
Minus
Select username, country from table2;
```

The above minus query works in RDBMS but i want the same result using hive. Can we use joins here in hive to get the result? If so how to get proper result using hive query.

Answer (score 2):

Set operations (MINUS/EXCEPT/INTERSECT in addition to UNION) are supported as of Hive 2.3.0 (released on 17 July 2017)
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12764

#### Demo

```
create table table1 (username string, country string);
create table table2 (username string, country string);

insert into table1 values ('Danny','USA'),('Danny','USA'),('David','UK');
insert into table2 values ('David','UK'),('Michal','France');
```

---

```
select username, country from table1
minus
Select username, country from table2
;
```

---

```
+--------------+-------------+
| _u1.username | _u1.country |
+--------------+-------------+
| Danny        | USA         |
+--------------+-------------+
```

In older Hive version you can use -

```
select      username
           ,country

from        (           select 1 tab,username, country from table1
            union all   select 2 tab,username, country from table2
            ) t
       
group by    username
           ,country
           
having      count(case when tab = 2 then 1 end) = 0
;
```

---

```
+----------+---------+
| username | country |
+----------+---------+
| Danny    | USA     |
+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Man! you are awesome in hiveql +1 ;P

Comment: Does not seem to work with Hive. I get the error `FAILED: ParseException line 3:0 missing EOF at 'Select' near 'minus'`

Comment: Which version of Hive?

Answer (score 1):

You may utilize left join as follows

```
select table1.username, table1.country 
from table1 left join table2 
     on table1.username=table2.username and table1.country=table2.country 
where table2.username is NULL and table2.country is NULL;
```

Comment: Note that while it might fit the OP specific use-case, it not equivalent to MINUS operator. **(1)** Duplicated records in `table1` are kept (can be handled using DISTINCT) **(2)** NULL values will cause false-positives (can be handled by replacing the `=` operator with `<=>`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes , As minus and exist not usually  work in hive we can do minus operation by below LEFT JOIN condition.

```
SELECT t1.username, t1.country
FROM
(select username, country from table1) t1
LEFT JOIN 
(Select username, country from table2) t2
ON t1.username =t2.username
AND t1.country =t2.country
WHERE t1.username IS NULL
```

IMP NOTE:Please do use WHERE CLAUSE FOR NULL Operations  instead of AND after join condition this will have different results.